# Returning value from async Action invoked on Dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, dispatcher

I'm developing a WPF XBAP application that provides API to user through JavaScript by using BrowserInteropHelper. After rewriting managed part in new async-await fashion there is a need to wait until async operation is finished without making calling method async Task itself. I have :

```
public string SyncMethod(object parameter)
{
    var sender = CurrentPage as MainView; // interop
    var result = string.Empty;
    if (sender != null)
    sender.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                 new Action(async () =>
                                                {
                                                    try
                                                    {
                                                        result = await sender.AsyncMethod(parameter.ToString());
                                                    }
                                                    catch (Exception exception)
                                                    {
                                                        result = exception.Message;
                                                    }
                                                }));
    return result;        
}
```

This method returns string.Empty because that happens right after execution. I've tried to assign this action to DispatcherOperation and do while(dispatcherOperation.Status != Completed) { Wait(); }, but even after execution the value is still empty. dispatcherOperation.Task.Wait() or dispatcherOperation.Task.ContinueWith() also didn't help.
***edit***
Also tried

```
var op = sender.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...);
op.Completed += (s, e) => { var t = result; };
```

But t is empty too because assignment happens before awaiting of asynchronous method. 
***edit*** 
Long story short, SyncMethod JavaScript interop handler helper wrapper, and all operations it runs must be on Dispatcher. AsyncMethod is async Task< T > and works perfectly when executed and awaited from inside application, i.e. inside some button handler. It has a lot of UI-dependent logic (showing status progressbar, changing cursor, etc.).
***edit***
AsyncMethod :

```
public async Task<string> AsyncMethod(string input)
{
    UIHelpers.SetBusyState(); // overriding mouse cursor via Application.Current.Dispatcher
    ProgressText = string.Empty; // viewmodel property reflected in ui
    var tasksInputData = ParseInput(input);    
    var tasksList = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var taskInputDataObject in tasksInputData)
    {
        var currentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {            
            using (var a = new AutoBusyHandler("Running operation" + taskInputData.OperationName))
            { // setting busy property true/false via Application.Current.Dispatcher
                var databaseOperationResult = DAL.SomeLongRunningMethod(taskInputDataObject);
                ProgressText += databaseOperationResult;
            }
        });
        tasksList.Add(insertCurrentRecordTask);
    }    
    var allTasksFinished = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasksList.ToArray(), (list) =>
    {        
        return ProgressText;
    });
    return await allTasksFinished;    
}
```

Comment: What's the point of using `Dispatcher.Invoke` here?  You're not touching a UI element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After rewriting managed part in new async-await fashion there is a need to wait until async operation is finished without making calling method async Task itself.

This is one of the most difficult things you can try to do.

> AsyncMethod is async Task< T > and works perfectly when executed and awaited from inside application, i.e. inside some button handler. It has a lot of UI-dependent logic

And this situation makes it near-impossible.

---

The problem is that you need to block `SyncMethod` which is running on the UI thread, while allowing `AsyncMethod` to dispatch to the UI message queue.

There are a couple of approaches you could take:

1. Block on the `Task` using `Wait` or `Result`. You can avoid the [deadlock problem described on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) by using `ConfigureAwait(false)` in `AsyncMethod`. This means `AsyncMethod` will **have** to be refactored to replace UI-dependent logic with `IProgress<T>` or other nonblocking callbacks.
2. Install a nested message loop. This should work but you'll have to think through all the re-entrancy ramifications.

Personally, I think (1) is cleaner.

Comment: Was just about to re-write my answer to say something like this, based on OP's comments, although I didn't think of option #2.

Comment: Tried ConfigureAwait(false), didn't have any effect. Blocking via Result worked, but UI updates ( BusyIndicator actually - using same approach as described here - http://adamsteinert.com/blog/2011/10/busy-indicators-and-many-threads/ ) now doesn't happen. Now looking for solution of this problem. Thanks for blog link, gonna dig deeper.

Comment: Is your `AsyncMethod` actually asynchronous? The only reason `ConfigureAwait(false)` would not have an effect is if all things `await`ed were already complete or synchronous.

Comment: AsyncMethod runs database operations (let's say multiple inserts) and returns newly inserted row ids (see third edit of first post). I tried to do ConfigureAwait(false) on all insert tasks plus last one that returns global result.

Comment: @Demodave: You can see some examples of different approaches here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
var are = new AutoResetEvent(true);
sender.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,                                      
        new Action(async () =>
        {
           try { ... } catch { ... } finally { are.Set(); }
        }));



are.WaitOne();
return result;
```

are.WaitOne() will tell AutoResetEvent to wait until it is signaled which will happen when dispatcher action reaches finally block where are.Set() is called.

Comment: That's very much overthinking the problem.  You don't need to go through so much effort to wait until a task has completed; it provides a method (two in fact) that do exactly that.

Comment: AsyncMethod runs after WaitOne() successully, but blocks UI and never returns (only application closing, and returns empty).

Comment: my bad, it was supposed to be var are = new AutoResetEvent(true); -> true as a parameter, not false; I updated the code above.

Comment: Code have same result as original one. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

This solved it for me.

[Add Task delay for invoker to complete](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ccb5a935-0912-40c4-8b68-db08c9d94474/c-wpf-multithreading-cannot-return-the-actual-value-from-dispatcherbegininvoke-in-vs2013?forum=wpf).

```
public string SyncMethod(object parameter)  
{
    var sender = CurrentPage as MainView; // interop
    var result = string.Empty;

    if (sender != null)
    {
        await sender.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            new Func<Task>(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    result = await sender.AsyncMethod(parameter.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    result = exception.Message;
                }
            }));
    }

    await Task.Delay(200); // <-- Here
    return result;        
}
```